# How to read large XML node of SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Can anyone help me with read large file?
I reading and **item** like that:

```
    $xmlReader = new XMLReader();
    $xmlReader->open($path);

    while ($xmlReader->read() && $xmlReader->name !== 'item') ;

    while ($xmlReader->name == 'item')
    {
      $node = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlReader->readOuterXML());
      foreach($node->properties as $property)
      {
        var_dump($property->price); //empty class SimpleXMLElement
        var_dump($property->attributes()); //empty class SimpleXMLElement
      }

      $xmlReader->next('item');
    }

    $xmlReader->close();
```

So i cant to read **$property->price** because i receive **empty class SimpleXMLElement**

The same situation with attribute **sku** i also receive **empty class SimpleXMLElement**

And i can't convert in *(string)* because i receive empty string.

How to read the children node?
Source XML:

```
<items>
            <item>
                <code>be274178-9039-11e6-86d0-001e6727034e</code>
                <delete>0</delete>
                <title>Полотенцесушитель М-обр. 500*500 нар. р. 1" арт.00004-5050</title>
                <category>13760cb9-8f7b-11e6-86d0-001e6727034e</category>
                <producer>5a457cfd-b088-11e2-9c54-001e6727034e</producer>
                <properties>
                    <property sku="40 451">
                        <price>2831.00</price>
                        <characteristics>
                            <characteristic>
                                <title>Свойство</title>
                                <value>накопление</value>
                                <filter>0</filter>
                                <visible>0</visible>
                            </characteristic>
                            <characteristic>
                                <title>Форма</title>
                                <value>М-образный</value>
                                <filter>1</filter>
                                <visible>1</visible>
                            </characteristic>

                        </characteristics>
                    </property>
                    <property sku="40 464">
                        <price>3442.00</price>
                        <characteristics>
                            <characteristic>
                                <title>Свойство</title>
                                <value>накопление</value>
                                <filter>0</filter>
                                <visible>0</visible>
                            </characteristic>
                        </characteristics>
                    </property>

                </properties>

            </item>
        </items>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
foreach($node->properties->property as $property)
```

because it's only one `<properties>` elements but many `<property>` elements.

See [Example #4 Accessing non-unique elements in SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) in the PHP Manual:

> When multiple instances of an element exist as children of a single parent element, normal iteration techniques apply.
>
> ```
> <?php
> include 'example.php';
>
> $movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
>
> /* For each <character> node, we echo a separate <name>. */
> foreach ($movies->movie->characters->character as $character) {
>    echo $character->name, ' played by ', $character->actor, PHP_EOL;
> }
>
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Thank you. Not so obvious :)